# $skip has no effect on the end point to list schemaExtensions in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=10&$skip=10` end point to GET 10 items , skipping the first 10 items (paging) but every time the results are the same and skip is ignored as if I am calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=10` . What could I be doing wrong? Or is skip not supported in this API?Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD resources uses a [`skipToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skiptoken-parameter) rather than [`skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skip-parameter). When you call `/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=10`, Graph will return a `nextLink` for the following page:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=10&$skiptoken=%7B%22token%22%3a%22%2bRID%3a~F7weALI27DguAAAAAAAAAA%3d%3d%23RT%3a1%23TRC%3a10%23ISV%3a2%23IEO%3a65551%23QCF%3a1%23FPC%3aAgEAAADCAC8AAMAuABSBAAoCBEAAgMAABgQARYKAAJjgEQArBJAFEcDoCwaoQQCgAAhAAggAEAAACLABgjEEAgIADAIIgCWgAsAEH4BqgAzABSCAACYGAKAeAGAAAAAgMQcAAABAOBAAMgAhACAARgBgABCwQIgJCATxgAAxAAARKQACgAAIAAQygAAgTCQQIAEQiCASAAkICMAYgASADsABFIEIAAAIZHwAAwAAAIAQgAINAAUAoGEADHgCIgAAoB0AEQBAgBCA%22%2c%22range%22%3a%7B%22min%22%3a%22%22%2c%22max%22%3a%2205C1DFFFFFFFFC%22%7D%7D",
    "value": [
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for confirming that skip won't work for schemaExtensions which comes under group resource type. Yes I did notice the `@odata.nextLink` with which another call needs to be made to get paging going.